# How to merge Multiple lines into one line only if the previous line ends with backslash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, line

I have the following file:

```
Hi
How \
are \ 
you\
?

Bye
```

I want to get this output:

```
Hi
How are you?

Bye
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: There's a blank at the end of the third line.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/\\ *\n//g' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that \ is at the end of each line with no spaces after:

```
sed -z 's/\\\n//g' file
```

Consume the file with no line endings (-z) and then replace and \ and an new line with nothing.

Comment: note that BSD sed does not support `-z`.

Comment: Nor does BSD support `\n` This is GNU sed only.

Comment: @dawg BSD sed does support \n in pattern as in s/pattern/replace/

Answer (score 2):

Joining lines on `\` escaped newline character is exactly what the shell's `read` command will do if omitting its `-r` option flag.

So here is an example of reading the input file with `read` without a `-r` flag, and printing the result:

`input.txt`

```
Hi
How \
are \
you\
?

Bye
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# shellcheck disable=SC2162 # Explicitly desired backslash escaping
while IFS= read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  printf %s\\n "$line"
done <input.txt
```

Actual print-out result:

```
Hi
How are you?

Bye
```

---

Bash's `help read` extract:

> **`-r`** do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

[SshellCheck SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162)

Comment: note that this also converts \\ to \

Answer (score 1):

A portable `sed` way:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
Hi
How \
are \
you\
?

Bye
[STEP 102] $ sed -e :go -e '/\\$/!b' -e 'N;s/\\\n//;bgo' file
Hi
How are you?

Bye
[STEP 103] $
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Found a more concise one on [sed1line](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) page:

```
sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta'
```

Comment: It is nice to cite your sources, but it would have been even nicer to give a detailed explanation of the various `sed` arguments and commands in-use.

Comment: @LéaGris it's not easy to explain tricky sed. i use the sed debugger "sedsed": https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
echo 'Hi
How \
are \
you\
?

Bye' | awk '/\\$/ {sub(/\\$/, ""); printf "%s", $0; next} 1'
```

Prints:

```
Hi
How are you?

Bye
```

If you have trailing spaces after the `\`:

```
awk '/\\[ \t]*$/ {sub(/\\[ \t]*$/, ""); printf "%s", $0; next} 1' file
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -lpE 's/\\\h*\n//g' file
```

Comment: Will this work properly if backslash will appear inside line?

Comment: The second `awk` and the `perl` yes since it is anchored to the end of the line. I just fixed the first `awk` with an anchor.